# Nginx location regex to handle permalinks of multiple WordPress sites in /sub/directories

Tags: regex, wordpress, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I'm looking for a dynamic solution to handle pretty permalinks of multiple WordPress sites (nodes) installed in subdirectories.

The sites are accessible using URLs like this (I use `cluster` and `node` to denote the structure, but they're different for every case, but they always follow the same structure, and nodes are the directories that contain the WordPress root files):

https://www.domain.tld/cluster1/node1/

And what I'm trying to avoid is to create one rule per node like this:

```
location /cluster1/node1/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /cluster1/node1/index.php$is_args$args;
}

location /cluster2/node2/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /cluster2/node2/index.php$is_args$args;
}

location /cluster3/node3/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /cluster3/node3/index.php$is_args$args;
}

location /cluster4/node4/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /cluster4/node4/index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

That works, but there are over 43 nodes (constantly changes). So, I've tried the following:

```
location /([^/]+)/([^/]+)/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/$2/index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Shows the *homepage* correctly, but shows a 404 for the pages of the nodes (like https://www.domain.tld/cluster1/node1/page/) (rendered by Nginx not WordPress).

```
location ~ ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/$2/index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

But that makes the PHP file being downloaded as a file called `download`.

```
location ~ /([^/]+)/([^/]+)/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/$2/index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

The same as the previous.

```
location ^~ /([^/]+)/([^/]+)/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/$2/index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

This makes the *homepage* of that node download the same as the previous attempt, but shows a 404 for the pages of the nodes (like https://www.domain.tld/cluster1/node1/page/) (rendered by Nginx not WordPress).

Any clue of why none of the above works? Any suggestion on how to make it work?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a regular expression `location` block to capture the parameters for the internal redirection to the correct `index.php` handler. The regular expression `location` is declared using the `~` or `~*` modifiers. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

The regular expressions are evaluated in order, so the `location` for `\.php$` **must** be placed above the `location` you are inserting. Otherwise, the PHP file will be downloaded instead of being executed.

For example:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    ...
}
location ~ ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/$2/index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! But the nodes respond very slowly (+10s TTFB). Any suggestion to improve the performance? The difference vs. plain `location` is huge. The performance drop seems to be due to the location rule being placed after the `\.php$` handler.

Comment: Actually, never mind. The performance issue persists despite config changes. Is not related to this. Thank you again, @Richard!